# Querying related objects

Tags: soql, custom-object, relationships, master-detail

I have a relationship between objects as below:

`User->Contacts->Account->Parent`

I am trying to get the parent id using the following SOQL query:

```
[Select user.contacts.account.parentid from user where Id="15 digit id"];
```

But I get an output as query,query. I tried going one level up by using this SOQL:

```
[select contact.account.parentid from contact];
```

and I get the required parent id. I am not sure why it does not work in the first query when I go one level deeper in the object relationship.

Comment: User has many contacts ?

Comment: this is because the tool you are using to display the results has to traverse a 1:n relationship and doesn't have an easy way to show multiple rows of results; the query from a single Contact only has one result - hence displayable

Comment: User has only one contact ( does it matter if user has different contacts?)

Comment: Then why are you using user.contacts instead of user.contact ?

Comment: @crop1645 Is there any alternative query which I can use in my Developer console to view the parent id?

Comment: sure -- write execute anonymous apex with system.debug output

Comment: Yes it will make lots of difference, read parent to child vs child to parent limitations here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Contact is a PARENT of user, then `User.Contact` (instead of `Contacts`) should do the trick.

If it is a CHILD, then you can't really query like that, because you may have many contacts for a given user. In that case, the ideal query would be this:

```
[select User.Id,
        (select contact.account.parentid from contacts)
   from User
   where Id = 'XXX'];
```

That will give you ALL the parentIds for ALL the contacts.

Comment: FYI you can get the relationship name programmatically: `system.debug(User.ContactId.getDescribe().getRelationshipName());`

Comment: `contact.` is superfluous

Comment: @sebastian - I guess there is no master detail or lookup relationship involved here , it just user are related to contact and contact are related to account. User has only one contact.

Comment: Well, that's impossible (the lack of relationships). It simply must be implied. Use User.Contact (not User.Contacts) or you can get the relationship name from the sample on @AdrianLarson 's post

Comment: Its actually one to one relationship between user<->contact<->account<->parent.

Comment: The same applies. Have you even tried my code? If so, what happened?

Comment: I get - Didn't understand relationship error. I guess I can get user from contacts but not the other way.